# How do I add a JScrollPane to this JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am making a chatbot using a Java GUI template and everything works fine it's just that I am unable to add a `JScrollPane` to a `JPanel` that was created in a customizer class. I want the panel to have a scroll bar only if the number of `JButton` controls (in the form of chats) exceeds the size of the panel. This panel is in the second screen of my GUI.

Does it have anything to do with the fact that my GUI has 2 screens? This is the code in my View Outputs and I'm wondering what I can do to make it work?

```
public ViewOutputs() {

        chatPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(chatPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        chatPanel.setOpaque(true);

        chatPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 349));
        chatPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        chatPanel.setBorder(LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatPanel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 349));

        scrollPane.add(chatPanel);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);

}
```

This is what runs without adding any JScrollPane.
[Screen 2 of my Java GUI Chatbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hMow.png)

Comment: In your code example, you only add the chatPanel to the scrollPane. If you also want your chat radio buttons (Not JButtons?) in a scroll panel, then you'll need to create another scrollPane to put them into?

Comment: [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: My problem isn't with the JButtons or RadioButtons it's just that I don't know how to add a JScrollPane to my Jpanel because whenever I try to do so, nothing shows up. (Not even the JPanel)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. And a tip: add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* someone of a new comment.

Comment: Don't do `scrollPane.add(chatPanel);` and make sure you add the scroll pane to something. `setPreferredSize` isn't a great idea either